# Netplan wireless bridge Ubuntu 18

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, netplan

I am trying to create a bridge for my wireless NIC (wlp4s0) with the intention to provide direct access to it from a KVM. I also intend to share the ethernet NIC the same way, but am only having trouble with the wireless

NICs:
   ethernet: enp3s0
   wireless: wlp4s0

This works:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            addresses: []
    wifis:
        wlp4s0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            access-points:
                "MYWIFI":
                    password: "password"
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [enp3s0]
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

The result is a working wireless connection, and a working bridge of the ethernet NIC, both of which get assigned an IP from the dhcp on the connected router and everything works.

If I change it to the following

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
    wifis:
        wlp4s0:
            addresses: []
            access-points:
                "MYWIFI":
                    password: "password"
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [wlp4s0]
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

I get a working connection on the ethernet NIC (with a dynamic IP from the router), both the wlp4s0 and br0 devices appear as UP if I run ifconfig, but neither of them are assigned an IP from the router and only the ethernet connection works.

There are no apparently errors if I run netplan in --debug mode, or in dmesg after applying the configuration

Comment: I've the same issue, I'd like to set the bridge on wifi interface and I can't do that. Have you try any solution?

Comment: No. I never found a solution. Didn't spend too much time on it though. Bought an extra wired NIC and used that instead.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1769668